# 文字列からキーワードを作りたい

Tags: common-lisp

:foo という、キーワードを作りたいのですが、

```
(intern ":FOO")
```

としても、|:FOO|というシンボルができるようです。
どうすれば、:fooが作れますか。

Answer (score 1):

ユーティリティライブラリの「[Alexandria](http://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/)」に`make-keyword`という関数があります。

```
(alexandria:make-keyword "FOO")
;=> :FOO
;   :EXTERNAL
```

Answer (score 0):

internで keywordパッケージにインターンしてください。

```
(intern "FOO" :keyword)
;=> :FOO
```

':fooのようなシンボルはkeywordパッケージのシンボルの略記で、'keyword:fooの略記ともみなせますので、keywordパッケージにインターンすることによって作成します。

```
(intern ":FOO")
```

としても現在のパッケージの下に、|:FOO|というシンボルが作成されるだけになります。